# how to prevent SQL injection in ruby on rails with post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-injection

I am getting a security error in my ROR code that SQL injection may be possible in one post request when I run The OWASP Zed Attack Proxy (ZAP) tool on my code.
I have a get_auth_token method which does not take any parameters , ZAP tool adds a query parameter in this request and on executing the modifier request the page loads fine  which is an issue

Below is the modified url with added query param

https://example.com/api/sessions/get_auth_token?query=query+AND+1%3D1+--+

get_auth_token implementation looks like this

```
def get_auth_token
  user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id], disabled: false) 
 if session[:user_id]
  if user
  token = AuthToken.issue(user_id:user.username)
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  session[:username] = user.username
  session[:project_id] = user.get_setting('xyz', nil)
  User.update(user.id, :token=>token)
```

I do not want to convert this request to GET. I have gone through many examples for SQL injection prevention , they all focus on methods which accept some param. My method does not accept any param. How can I make sure that it does not accept any external param to prevent this SQL injection

Comment: This looks like it could be a false positive. If possible, post what the tool is claiming. I've seen tools that run a request, and record it's output, then run the same request with additional SQL-injection-trying params, and if the result is different (even if there's just a timestamp difference), it thinks the injection worked. In this case it looks like you are generating and returning a new auth token, which would differ between requests.

Comment: The tool is claiming that the page results are modified due to external query param. Even if the results are not modified I want to make sure that if external param is passed my application raises an error.

Comment: You could always do something like `raise if params[:query]`, but littering your code with useless stuff to please a tool isn't ideal. You can configure app-wide to raise an error on any unpermitted paramters with `config.action_controller.raise_on_unfiltered_parameters = true`, then use strong_parameters on every controller, but that still may not satisfy this tool, because a 500 will render differently from a request with no params. These tools are dumb, and are intended to help you audit yourself, but only you know your app completely.